# Where error in multiple count?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
   count(ProductID) as CountAllProducts,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '1' THEN ProductID ELSE 0 END) as CountPriceType1,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '2' THEN ProductID ELSE 0 END) as CountPriceType2
FROM Products
```

*We are get not right results:*

```
CountAllProducts   CountPriceType1   CountPriceType2
     10                 10                 10
```

*But should be:*

```
CountAllProducts   CountPriceType1   CountPriceType2
     10                 10                 0
```

*Tell me please where error?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT() counts 1 for any row where the argument is non-null.

In other words, the count of zeroes is the same as the count of 1's or the count of bananas or anything else.

You probably want this:

```
SELECT 
   count(ProductID) as CountAllProducts,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '1' THEN ProductID ELSE NULL END) as CountPriceType1,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '2' THEN ProductID ELSE NULL END) as CountPriceType2
FROM Products
```

You can shorten this a bit, because `CASE` returns NULL implicitly if the value matches no case.

```
SELECT 
   count(ProductID) as CountAllProducts,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '1' THEN ProductID END) as CountPriceType1,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '2' THEN ProductID END) as CountPriceType2
FROM Products
```

Another alternative is to use SUM() instead of COUNT(), and make sure the argument to SUM() is either 1 (do count it) or 0 (don't count it). Because the sum of a bunch of 1's and 0's is equal to the count of the 1's.

```
SELECT 
   count(ProductID) as CountAllProducts,
   SUM(CASE WHEN PriceType = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountPriceType1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN PriceType = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountPriceType2
FROM Products
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` counts non null values so even a `0` is counted

```
SELECT 
   count(ProductID) as CountAllProducts,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '1' THEN ProductID ELSE NULL END) as CountPriceType1,
   count(CASE WHEN PriceType = '2' THEN ProductID ELSE NULL END) as CountPriceType2
FROM Products
```

or

```
SELECT 
   count(ProductID) as CountAllProducts,
   sum(PriceType = '1') as CountPriceType1,
   sum(PriceType = '2') as CountPriceType2
FROM Products
```